# MongoDB each each cluster is on a different server or that they all in one

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing

I am starting to use MongoDB and yet I am developing the first project with this. I can not to predict how volume of clients and usage it gonna to receive but I want to develop it from the beginning to be high volume handled.

I have heard about clusters and I saw the demonstrations in MongoDB official website.

And here is my question (cutted to small semi-questions):

1. Are clusters are different servers or that they are just pieces of one big server?
2. Maybe it seems a bit not related, but how Facebook or huge database handles its data across countries? I mean, they have users from Asia and from America. Surely with different servers, how the system knows how to host, aggregate and deliver with the right server? Is it automatically or that it is a tool that a third party supply to such large databases?
3. If I am using clusters, shall I still just insert the data to the database and the Mongo will manipulate them in cluster by it's own, or shall I do that manually?
4. I have a cloud VPS. Should I continue work with this for Mongo or maybe I should really consider about AWS / Google Cloud Platform / etc..?

And another important thing is: Im from Israel, and the clouds I have mentioned above are probably from Europe at least or even more far.
It will probably cause in high latency, is not it?

Thanks.

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: Extra tip *".. how Facebook does it..."* seems to be a common theme in questions you are asking. You really should not be thinking about that since you're not Facebook, and nor is anything you are building likely to be on par with, at least overnight. If you want to learn something about "Facebook", then they did not get there overnight either. They started small. So should you. Learn the things about scaling up as the need arises. Believe there was a famous quote about "Premature optimization", that if you've never heard of you should look up. Anyhow "Off-topic". Talk to the DBA's

Comment: I am just asking how those clusters work.. And I if it is illegal posting about MongoDB here, then why there is a tag for it?

Comment: Why is there a tag for a lot of things? Cluster computing can be a "programming" topic. But your question is not. The tag except for [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) says it quite clearly. This is about "database configuration", so that's the site where you ask the questions related to the DBA like things. That's why there's a separate site. Please play nice and use it.